# iOS get Eve Motion sensor status programatically

Tags: ios, homekit

is it possible to get the Eve Motion sensor status using the HomeKit framework? I want to trigger some custom functions from my app when the sensor detected someone.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question. I tried the sensor in the Apple Store and is easy to access the motion sensor status using the Apple HomeKit library.

Comment: how did you do this? were you able to access sensor data from Xcode?